# UITableViewController selectionStyle none not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my UITableViewController custom class, I am using this in `cellRowRowAtIndexPath` :

```
cell?.selectionStyle = .none
```

The selection color however remains gray

Comment: Try this `cell.selectionStyle = .none`

Comment: You can do using     cell.selectionStyle = .none     OR  you can set cell selection style none from stroyBoard

Comment: which version swift 2 or 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

`cell.selectionStyle = none` 
 OR 
From `StoryBoard` you can select `cell selection style None`,
 
 [image]

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4+** This will definitely work.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // check for which cell you want this to happen here
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this,

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")! as
    UITableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
```